# Combine multiple rows into one single

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2014

I have something like this in a table

```
COUNTRY SCOPE1   SCOPE2 SCOPE3  SCOPE4  SCOPE5
UK          Y    NULL   NULL    NULL    NULL
UK      NULL          Y NULL    NULL    NULL
UK      NULL     NULL      Y    NULL    NULL
```

I need output as single Row

```
COUNTRY SCOPE1  SCOPE2  SCOPE3  SCOPE4  SCOPE5
UK          Y        Y       Y  NULL    NULL
```

Can anybody help on this in MS SQL Server 2014?

Comment: What if you have multiple value for one scope, for e.g if line 1 scope1 = 'Y' for UK, line 2 scope1 = 'X' for UK, then in result UK will have scope1 = ??

Comment: The data sheet which I have has only Y or NULL. I believe we cannot combine if it has duplicate entries.

Comment: Then you could simply use an aggregate function as in aswers below.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use `MAX` function.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(50),
    SCOPE1 VARCHAR(3),
   SCOPE2 VARCHAR(3),
   SCOPE3 VARCHAR(3),
   SCOPE4 VARCHAR(3),
   SCOPE5 VARCHAR(3)
);


INSERT INTO T VALUES ('UK','Y',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('UK',NULL,'Y',NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('UK',NULL,NULL,'Y',NULL,NULL);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT COUNTRY ,
        MAX(SCOPE1) AS SCOPE1,
        MAX(SCOPE2) AS SCOPE2,
        MAX(SCOPE3) AS SCOPE3,
        MAX(SCOPE4) AS SCOPE4,
        MAX(SCOPE5) AS SCOPE5
FROM T
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/807f2/2/0)**:

```
| COUNTRY | SCOPE1 | SCOPE2 | SCOPE3 | SCOPE4 | SCOPE5 |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      UK |      Y |      Y |      Y | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help !!
It helped !

Comment: @Parsu No problem glad to help  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregate function `max` or `min` both will work for your data set

```
SELECT COUNTRY ,
        MAX(SCOPE1) as  SCOPE1,
        MAX(SCOPE2) as  SCOPE2,
        MAX(SCOPE3) as  SCOPE3,
        MAX(SCOPE4) as  SCOPE4,
        MAX(SCOPE5) as  SCOPE5
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3960c/1

```
COUNTRY     SCOPE1  SCOPE2  SCOPE3  SCOPE4  SCOPE5
UK           Y        Y       Y     (null)  (null)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNTRY ,
        min(SCOPE1) as  SCOPE1,
        min(SCOPE2) as  SCOPE2,
        min(SCOPE3) as  SCOPE3,
        min(SCOPE4) as  SCOPE4,
        min(SCOPE5) as  SCOPE5
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3960c/2

```
COUNTRY     SCOPE1  SCOPE2  SCOPE3  SCOPE4  SCOPE5
UK            Y      Y         Y    (null)  (null)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Zaynul !!